# explain relative and absolute positioning to an absolute beginner?

Tags: html, css

Can you please relative and absolute positioning to me,I don't understand what they mean by both terms. I just want to get an alternative explanation and the run it through my own understanding to see if I am right.

Comment: No. Concepts in CSS build on one another, and being an absolute beginner is no place to be learning about positioning. First, get yourself a good grounding on how [Normal Flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) works.

Comment: this may easy to understand   http://designshack.net/articles/css/the-lowdown-on-absolute-vs-relative-positioning/

Comment: A relatively positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position. The absolutely positioned element is relative to the first parent container that has absolute or relative positioning. More info on: https://kolosek.com/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute

Answer (score 0):

- Let's start with position: static; Static is the default, so if nothing is specified, the element is static. It is the
  normal flow of elements on the page. For example when the element
  does not fit on the line, it goes to the next line.
- Then we have position: relative; Think of this as relative to its own position. Now we can use left, right, top and bottom to shift the
  element from its original position.
- Also, when setting an element's position to relative, the origin of any absolute child elements, is reset. In other words, position (0,0) of an absolute child element is the same as the relative parent.
- The next one is position: absolute; The element is now outside the normal flow of elements on the page. The position is measured from the origin of the first relative parent found. If no such parent is found, its
  position will be relative the the browser window, which is the same
  as position: fixed;